# Holocentric - Does anyone use it for modeling?

Tags: uml

A simple poll essentially.... Searching google for Holocentric reveals very little about the takeup of product. Has anyone used it? Is it any good good?

Answer (score 0):

They are an Australian company and I believe most of their sales have been in Australia, I've only ever seen the product used in various Aus government organisations where it seems to be quite popular. In general it tends to end up being used more as a business modelling tool than a design tool.

While it does support UML its not that great at it.